# How to calculate air flow from a pressurized tank?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow

I am writing an app that deals with simulated air brakes, and I need to simulate the release of air from one container of a given pressure into another container of a lower pressure. It doesn't have to be perfect, as this is just a rail simulator, but I need the air pressure to seem realistic. In reading about how to simulate air flow from an orifice, I was a little overwhelmed. Is there a way to get it "close enough" for my needs?

Comment: You can assume that flow is proportional to pressure difference and chose a proportionality constant that gives you the right time scale for the equalization of pressure in your system. Will this be realistic? Probably not for a safety critical application, but for something that "looks about right" it might be.

Comment: @CuriousOne, that's a very practical and excellent suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way is to model your pneumatic system as an electrical circuit analogy. This approach can get you close to the true physical behavior as long as you don't have thermal effects due to gas flow and if you are able to 'lump' a continuum of parameters as a single parameter.

In the pneumatic-electrical circuit analogy volumes provide a compliant space for the has to compress and expand, and so volume can be expressed analogous to capacitance. And the orifice through which the gas flows is analogous to electrical resistance. Flow is analogous to the electrical current, and pressure to voltage.

You didn't show a diagram of your specific problem, but that's where you would start. And from that diagram you would draw the electrical circuit analogy. Start with a linear circuit- linear resistance and compliance. But you find that for resistance a quadratic relationship better models the component of flow resistance: $\Delta P=Q^2R$. You'll find this to be a close approximation to the orifice equations you researched. The pressure due to compliance is $P= \frac{1}{C} \int Q dt$. And compliance is $C= \frac{V}{P_a}$ where $V$ is the volume of the space you are considering to be the compliance, and $P_a$ is the absolute barometric pressure. In an electrical circuit there is 'ground' voltage and in the analogy that's barometric pressure which can be taken as zero by using gauge pressures.

Comment: This sounds like the right approach, but you'll have to forgive my ignorance here. What does Q represent in the equations?

Comment: Sorry. $Q$ is volumetric flow rate. $\Delta P$ is the difference in pressure across the flow restriction. $C$ is the compliance of a volumetric space due to the resilience of gas compression (units are for example m^3/Pa). And $R$ is the flow resistance (units are for example Pa/(m^3/sec)^2 ).

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, I should solve for $Q$ by doing $Q^2 = \Delta PR$. And if I had a 140psi tank that I vented to a 120psi tank, then $P=20$. How would I find R though?

Comment: To find $R$ just run an experiment by ramping flow through the orifice and measuring the delta P. Fit the data to the function

Comment: That's the problem, I can't do that. This is for a rail simulator, and it will be 130-140psi tanks releasing air into a small air hose. I don't have access to an actual locomotive to test this with, that's why I was willing to settle for 'close enough'. Is $R$ just a coefficient for resistance of the shape of the orifice? Almost like an efficiency rating? Like if $R$ was $0.70$ then the orifice would have 30% resistance...or is that an incorrect understanding?

Comment: Is the source pressure 130 - 140 psi, psia or psig (absolute or gauge)?

Answer (score 0):

For air, when the downstream absolute pressure is 52.8% or less of the upstream absolute pressure, the flow is choked (limited by the sonic velocity, mass flow rate independent of the sink pressure).  Your comment above says the source pressure is about 130 psi, so depending on the hose  (sink) pressure the flow may very well be choked.

You can find relationships for choked (and non-choked) flow in textbooks and articles on fluid flow.  For example, see articles on the web, or a text that discusses fluid flow, such as Elements of Thermodynamics and Heat Transfer by Obert and Young, or Flow of Fluids through Valves, Fittings, and Pipe, Crane Technical Paper 410.  The Crane reference provides equations, and graphs of discharge coefficients and other parameters in the equations.